# Creating a "database" with excel with VBA Userform

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim actual_sheet As String

actual_sheet = "Sheet1"

Dim data_base As Variant

data_base = Sheets(actual_sheet).Range("G4:K100000")

nome = TextBox1.Value
Age = TextBox2.Value
Adress = TextBox3.Value
Phone = TextBox4.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(data_base)

    Line_at = data_base(i, 1)

    If Line_at = "" Then

        ' id
        data_base(i, 1) = i
        'name
        data_base(i, 2) = nome
        'age
        data_base(i, 3) = Age
        'adress
        data_base(i, 4) = Adress
        'phone
        data_base(i, 5) = Phone

        Exit For

    End If

Next


Sheets(actual_sheet).Range("G4:K100000") = database

UserNew.Hide



End Sub
```

I have a form for a user called `UserNew` and I want some information to a 'database' *just a table for exercise * , but when i click the CommandButton_1 nothing happens to my "data_base", i debugged and i saw that the values are actually getting passed, but i think the problem it's with the writting part ... I don't know is not working ....
Any help is appreciated.

Actually i can pass the values to a sub(name,age,address,phone) , but there's a way to this automatically like this example ?

Comment: Most of your code uses a variable called **`data_base`**, but at the end, your code sets the range to a previously-unused variable **`database`**. This is why you should always use `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've dim'd `data_base` but where you assign back to a range, you use `database`. Always, always put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declare all variables.